# Have Microsoft Windows tablet computer sales been significant?

Tags: computers

When people talk about the iPad they often mention that Windows-based tablet computers *never* took off (never had significant sales). Is this true? Did any company ever make make money building/selling Windows-based tablet computers?

Comment: Don't forget.. the Apple Newton failed first :)

Comment: I have a convertible that I love.  But it is not strictly a tablet.  I have seen quite a few people in sales using them.

Comment: Define `take off`, `make money` and `significant`. Else, not objectively answerable, except everybody made losses.

Comment: make money = turn a profit. Significant means > 1% of PC sales. Took off = became important to more than a niche market. The question is not limited to any version of Windows. Since Windows has been the main operating system for desktop computers (for the past many years) I'm looking at tablets which can run similar software to *most* desktop PC's.

Comment: Motion Computing http://www.motioncomputing.com/ has been selling Windows-based tablets since at least Windows XP Tablet Edition circa 2003. Although it's possible that they have been operating at a loss for 8 years, it would seem more likely that they have achieved some level of profit.

Comment: Is this skeptic question for general knowledge?

Comment: you'd have to define "windows tablet computer". Does that include the hybrid tablet/laptop systems as well (which in sales figures are often counted as laptops)?

Answer (score 5):

[Windows Tablet Sales Finally Being Tracked, Not in Last Place](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2011/07/21/windows-tablet-sales-finally-being-tracked-not-in-last-place/) (sourced from some company named "[Strategy Analytics](http://www.strategyanalytics.com/default.aspx?mod=reportabstractviewer&a0=6603)" with the full report costing $6K), data for Q2/2011:

**Millions of units shipped, Q2/2011:**

```
iOS:     9.3 Million
Android: 4.6 Million
Windows: 0.8 Million
QNX:     0.6 Million
Others:  0.1 Million
```

**% Global Market Share, Q2/2011:**

```
iOS:     61.3%
Android: 30.1%
Windows: 4.6%
QNX:     3.3%
Others:  0.3%
```

Answer (score 5):

**20 years of trying has only created niche markets for Windows Tablets**

It is worth reviewing a little history before attempting an answer to this question. The question asks whether Windows tablet PCs have ever been successful. I think this refers to Microsoft's Windows XP tablet edition in 2001. But Microsoft had launched a tablet OS in 1991. And even that wasn't the first (see potted history [here](http://www.osnews.com/story/22739/A_Short_History_of_the_Tablet_Computer/page2/)). The fact that much of this history is forgotten is a product of the lack of success of these products. Here is part of the story as told by [informationweek](http://www.informationweek.com/news/security/encryption/222300080?pgno=2) in january 2010:

> Between 1992 and 1994, a number of companies introduced hardware to run Windows for Pen Computing or PenPoint. Among them were EO, NCR, Samsung ... Dauphin, Fujitsu, TelePad, Compaq, Toshiba, and IBM. Few people remember that the original IBM ThinkPad was, as the name implies, a slate computer.
>
> The computer press was first enthusiastic, then very critical when pen computers did not sell. They measured pen computers against desktop PCs with Windows software and most of them found pen tablets difficult to use. They also criticized handwriting recognition and said it did not work. After that, pen computer companies failed.
>
> Momenta closed in 1992. They had used up US$40 million in venture capital. Samsung and NCR did not introduce new products. Pen pioneer GRiD was bought by AST for its manufacturing capacity. AST stopped all pen projects. Dauphin, which was started by a Korean businessman named Alan Yong, went bankrupt, owing IBM over $40 million. GO was taken over by AT&T, and AT&T closed the company in August 1994 (after the memorable "fax on the beach" TV commercials). GO had lost almost US$70 million in venture capital. Compaq, IBM, NEC, and Toshiba all stopped making consumer market pen products in 1994 and 1995.

So the first wave didn't make anyone any money.

The second wave could be argued to start in 2001 with this (from a 2005 [article](http://www.itworld.com/050627gatestablet) looking back on developments):

> Gates showed prototype Tablet PCs at the Comdex show in Las Vegas in 2001 -- a year ahead of their 2002 launch -- and at the show said in a company news release, "It's a PC that is virtually without limits and within five years I predict it will be the most popular form of PC sold in America."

The article further comments:

> It's now a little over three and a half years into the time period he set and to-date Tablet PC has managed to do only marginally better than the now defunct trade show. A handful of vendors market Tablet PCs, but specialist markets like health care account for a large percentage of sales. Other users and those in business have yet to take to the form-factor in a big way.

It also suggests that just over half a million tablets shipped in 2004. This number sounds optiistic compred to the one hard number I've found so far which unfortunately only covers European sales. Canalys estimate that they were only about 33,000 in 2004.

Unfortunately, few research reports or forecasts from the 2001-2009 period are easy to find (perhaps because nobody likes to see old but failed forecasts). But this quote from the [New York Times in 2009](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/10/05/technology/05tablet.html) (so pre iPad) and commenting on the Bill gates forecast quoted above sums up what seems to be the accepted wisdom:

> Tablets running Windows sell only a few hundred thousand units a year, mostly in business fields like health care and financial services.

This suggests that they have never accounted for more that a fraction of 1% of PC sales (which were >300m in 2010).

Comment: That's great stuff, Matt. Anything with newer information? I'm not limiting it to XP Tablet, I'm limiting it to Windows, from windows version 3 up to Windows 7 and later).

Comment: @john I've mostly found recent (post iPad) reviews. but I've added a pre iPad quote from an NYT overview of the tablet market which I think is an accurate overview.

Comment: only somewhat recent data I have is the company I work for. We replaced ALL our existing PCs in 2008, buying 800 laptops and 200 Windows tablet/laptop hybrids from Lenovo (the latter for sales, secretaries, and some managers). Yes, it's a niche market. For most people the form factor is less convenient than a real laptop, for most others it's more convenient but the extra cost is too high. For the consumer market, they were never offered there so of course they're not going to sell...